# Read byte string as xls file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, rabbitmq, xlrd

I have a JSON object consumed from a RabbitMQ queue which contains a *base64 encoded* xls file.
The structure is the following:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "excel_file": "0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQ...........",
    "other_field": "more data here",
    ...
    ...
}
```

Currently i do something like:

```
data = json.loads(msg)  # msg is the body of the message consumed from rabbitmq queue
file_bytes = bytes(data['excel_file'], 'utf8')  # returns: b'0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(file_bytes)  # returns: b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00...

# save data to file
with open('file.xls', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(decoded_bytes)

# open the saved file as xls for manipulation
with xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls') as f:
    sh0 = f.sheet_by_index(0)
    print(sh0.name)

"""Manipulate the xls file data with ease.""""
```

I don't want to create an xls file in my filesystem and delete it after manipulation.

So ideally, i would like to use something like `xlrd.loads()` (doesn't exists) to load directly the decoded data as xlrd object.

Just like `json.loads()` can do.

Anyone knows how to **load xls data directly** from bytearray for manipulation?

#### UPDATE

As @Raphael and @Masklinn suggested i utilized xlrd's `file_contents` to load xls data directly from bytes, without any file.

So the code now is the following:

```
data = json.loads(msg)  # msg is the body of the message consumed from rabbitmq queue
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(data['excel_file'])  # returns: b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00...

with xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=decoded_bytes) as f:
    sh0 = f.sheet_by_index(0)
    # manipulate the data as xlrd Book object
    # ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xlrd has also a `file_contents`  parameter. See the [docs](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.open_workbook) or this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472681/open-bytesio-xlsx-with-xlrd)

In general you can also use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) when  you have bytes and a file handle is required. `io.BytesIO(bytes)` behaves exactly as `open('file.bytes', 'rb)`

Comment: Also FWIW `b64decode` can take a string input, no need to encode it explicitly. You may want to call it with `validate=True` though, otherwise it just strips anything which isn't a b64 character then tries to decode the rest, which can lead to odd results.

Comment: Great. `file_contents` did the trick.
Found also another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52077212/10269515) utilizing pandas but i prefer the xlrd solution in my case.